# Read an environment variable from applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, applicationcontext

I need read an environment variable defined in my web.xml

```
<env-entry>
    <description>Path Repositorio NFS</description>
    <env-entry-name>PATH_ENV</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>C:/V3</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

from my `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="${PATH_ENV}/myprop.properties" />
</bean>
```

How can I do this ?

---

Finally I have done the next:

1 Define environment variable in context.xml:

```
<Environment name="PATH_ENV" type="java.lang.String"/>
```

2 Define env-entry in web.xml

```
<env-entry>
    <description>Path Repositorio NFS</description>
    <env-entry-name>PATH_ENV</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>/WEB-INF/</env-entry-value>
  </env-entry>
```

3 Define in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="configurationPath" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">  
    <property name="jndiName">  
        <value>java:comp/env/PATH_ENV</value>  
    </property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
       <property name="location">
            <bean factory-bean="configurationPath" factory-method="concat">
                <constructor-arg value="myprop.properties"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This is run correctly, However if I define a full path in:

```
<env-entry-value>C:/V3/</env-entry-value>
```

I have the next problem:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/C:/V3/aesantasa.properties]
```

I cant define a full path in env-entry-value Why?

Comment: In case anyone comes by this question, it should've been `<env-entry-value>file:C:/V3/</env-entry-value>`

Answer (score 4):

You can lookup JNDI entries (both environment entries and resources) with the JndiObjectFactoryBean or [`<jee:jndi-lookup>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee-jndi-lookup):

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="PATH_ENV" jndi-name="PATH_ENV"/>
```

(To use the jee-namespace, you must [declare](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee) it).

That defines a spring bean named "PATH_ENV" that contains (as a string) the path configured int the environment entry. You can now inject it into other beans:

```
<bean class="xy.Foo">
    <property name="path" ref="PATH_ENV"/>
</bean>
```

The remaining difficulty is concatenating the strings. (Unfortunately, there is no JndiPlaceholderConfigurer that would replace placeholders with JNDI environment entries, so you can't use the `${property}/foo` syntax to concatenate, and must supply yet another bean definition:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <bean factory-bean="PATH_ENV" factory-method="concat">
            <constructor-arg>/myprop.properties</constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

(code untested as I don't have a Spring project at hand to test it)

Comment: I cant read the context-param.Is this the correct way to read the context-param in applicationContext.xml ?

value="${PATH_ENV}/myprop.properties"

Comment: A context param is not the same as an environment entry. Your question says environment entry (`<env-entry>`), so why are you now talking about context parameters (`<context-param>`)? As for how to refer to it, I'll edit to include a sample.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PATH_ENV': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: El nombre PATH_ENV no este asociado a este contexto

Comment: This solution was most right for me, except that one needs to make sure that PATH_ENV starts with "file:"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context-param`, that will work.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>PATH_ENV</param-name>
    <param-value>C:/V3</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the following?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="file:C:/V3/myprop.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: the properties files need to have a relative path based on the same variable

Comment: why don't you put .properties files in resources or the similar folder in your project which is in classpath?

Answer (score -1):

I solved something, I think, similar.

I create a Windows System Variable with the changing part of the path:

```
my computer --> advanced options --> environment options --> Systeme Variable
```

And then with this I complete the path on Spring AppContext like this:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

   <property name="locations">  
       <list>
              <value>file:${PARENT_PATH}/conf/dev/jdbc.properties</value>
       <list>           
   </property>
</bean>
```

I don't know if really help, but for me works

Comment: My problem is that the Variable cant be a System Variable