# How to access env-entry value in spring xml files?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

I defined an environment variable in web.xml as below..

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>appName</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>myApp</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Now I want to access this value in spring mvc resources tag as below.

```
<mvc:resources order="-10" mapping="/robots.txt" 
        location="${jboss.home.dir}/${appName}/robots.txt" />
```

But the variable ${appName} is not resolving. Can you please help me out on how to read the environment entry in spring xml files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read an environment variable from applicationContext.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391474/read-an-environment-variable-from-applicationcontext-xml)

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: @ankur-singhal - I saw the post. It suggests to define JNDI lookup and refer the JNDI entry. But I am looking for a solution where I can access the variable like JBOSS environment properties -- ${jboss.home.dir}..

Comment: @M.Deinum - I am using spring 3.2.9 version.

Comment: Your question states clearly that yuo want the `${appName}` resolved so which is it? Make sure you have a `<context:property-placeholder />` in your configuration. You don't need to load a file but  you need it for placeholder replacement, especially for those not in the system properties or system environment.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thanks for your suggestion. I will give a try with adding the spring property-placeholder tag and let you know how it goes..

Comment: @M.Deinum - I added the <context:property-placeholder /> in my applicationContext.xml file. But still it didn't work..

Comment: Make sure that the `<context:property-placeholder />` is in the same context as `<mvc:resources />` it will only replace values in the context it is defined in.

Comment: @M.Denium - I suppose both are in same context, but I will double check and confirm.